# How to get data value in string C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net

I have an object like this. How can I parse the Name Surname from this object?

```
Object

{
    "HasError":false,
    "AlertType":"success",
    "AlertMessage":"Operation has completed successfully",
    "ModelErrors":[],
    "Data":{
        "Count":1,
        "Objects":
        [{
            "Id":291031530,
            "FirstName":"Alp",
            "LastName":"Uzan",
            "MiddleName":"",
            "Login":"alp"
        }]
    }
}
```

I'm getting this data to an external api using `HttpClient` but I can't parse it by values. Can you help with this, the `type of data` is `System.String`

Comment: Edit | Paste Special | Paste as JSON classes (assuming you're using VS and not Rider, etc.)

Comment: there is no property named "Surname"

Comment: Do you mean `"LastName"`?

Comment: Do you have an actual class object that represent the one in your json response?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options. The most type-safe way would be to define C# classes which represent the schema of your JSON content and then deserialise into an instance of those like so:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<DataObject> Objects { get; set; }
}

public class DataObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
}

public class  MyJSONObject
{
    public bool HasError { get; set; }
    public string AlertType { get; set; }
    public string AlertMessage { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

...

//Deserialise
var json = "<snip>";
var deserialised = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyJSONObject>(json);

//Extract the info you want
 Console.WriteLine(deserialised.Data.Objects[0].LastName);
```

A second, more quick and dirty way to do it would be to parse the JSON into a `JsonObject` (this is using System.Text.Json) and then extract out the info you need:

```
var jsonObj = JsonObject.Parse(Properties.Resources.JSON);
var objectsArray = ((JsonArray)y["Data"]["Objects"]);

Console.WriteLine(objectsArray[0]["LastName"]);
```

A similar method would work with Newtonsoft.Json as well, although you'd need to use `JObject` instead of `JsonObject` and `JArray` rather than `JsonArray` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use c#, save output in string and serialize, usa this library

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);

string Name= json.Data.Objects[0].FirstName

string Surname = json.Data.Objects[0].Lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `System.Text.Json`:

```cs
var jsonObject= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(jsonString);
```

Then you can use `jsonObject["Data"]["Objects"][0]["FirstName"]` to get the data.